# How to use condition select in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

By using this query I can get the result as I want but now there is another problematic `while` condition.

```
SELECT distinct 
    concat([Segment_0], '-' , [Segment_1], '-',[Segment_2])  As 'AcctCode',
    T1.[AcctName], 
    T2.[Name],
    concat(T3.[Code],'-',T3.[Name]),
    T0.[DebLTotal] AS 'ANNUAL BUDGET KSH',
    T0.[DebRLTotal] AS 'UTILISED BUDGET', 
    T3.[Name] , 
    T3.[Code], 
    (T0.[DebLTotal] - T0.[DebRLTotal]) AS 'BALANCE BUDGET',
    (SELECT concat(T3.Code , '-', T3.[Name]) WHERE T3.SegmentId = '1') AS 'Project',
    (SELECT concat(T3.Code , '-', T3.[Name]) WHERE T3.SegmentId = '2') AS 'Distt' 
FROM 
    OBGT T0 
INNER JOIN 
    OACT T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode] 
INNER JOIN 
    OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId] 
INNER JOIN 
    OASC T3 ON (T3.SegmentId = '1' AND T3.Code = [Segment_1] ) 
               OR (T3.SegmentId = '2' AND T3.Code = [Segment_2])
```

If I put `condition` in the `where` clause like `Project = '100' and Distt = '001'`, it gives me no data. It should be there.

```
concat([Segment_0], '-' , [Segment_1], '-', [Segment_2])
```

should also be changed according to the condition as we are joining `SegmentId` to those columns.

Please help

```
USE [RCTP_NGO]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OACT]    Script Date: 06/Nov/2015 4:28:56 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OACT](
    [AcctCode] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [AcctName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CurrTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [EndTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [Finanse] [char](1) NULL,
    [Groups] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [Budget] [char](1) NULL,
    [Frozen] [char](1) NULL,
    [Free_2] [char](1) NULL,
    [Postable] [char](1) NULL,
    [Fixed] [char](1) NULL,
    [Levels] [smallint] NULL,
    [ExportCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [GrpLine] [int] NULL,
    [FatherNum] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [AccntntCod] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [CashBox] [char](1) NULL,
    [GroupMask] [smallint] NULL,
    [RateTrans] [char](1) NULL,
    [TaxIncome] [char](1) NULL,
    [ExmIncome] [char](1) NULL,
    [ExtrMatch] [int] NULL,
    [IntrMatch] [int] NULL,
    [ActType] [char](1) NULL,
    [Transfered] [char](1) NULL,
    [BlncTrnsfr] [char](1) NULL,
    [OverType] [char](1) NULL,
    [OverCode] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [SysMatch] [int] NULL,
    [PrevYear] [char](1) NULL,
    [ActCurr] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [RateDifAct] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [SysTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FcTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [Protected] [char](1) NULL,
    [RealAcct] [char](1) NULL,
    [Advance] [char](1) NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [FrgnName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Details] [nvarchar](254) NULL,
    [ExtraSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [Project] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [RevalMatch] [char](1) NULL,
    [DataSource] [char](1) NULL,
    [LocMth] [char](1) NULL,
    [MTHCounter] [int] NULL,
    [BNKCounter] [int] NULL,
    [UserSign] [smallint] NULL,
    [LocManTran] [char](1) NULL,
    [LogInstanc] [int] NULL,
    [ObjType] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [ValidFor] [char](1) NULL,
    [ValidFrom] [datetime] NULL,
    [ValidTo] [datetime] NULL,
    [ValidComm] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [FrozenFor] [char](1) NULL,
    [FrozenFrom] [datetime] NULL,
    [FrozenTo] [datetime] NULL,
    [FrozenComm] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Counter] [int] NULL,
    [Segment_0] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_1] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_2] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_3] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_4] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_5] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_6] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_7] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_8] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Segment_9] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [FormatCode] [nvarchar](210) NULL,
    [CfwRlvnt] [char](1) NULL,
    [ExchRate] [char](1) NULL,
    [RevalAcct] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [LastRevBal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [LastRevDat] [datetime] NULL,
    [DfltVat] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [VatChange] [char](1) NULL,
    [Category] [int] NULL,
    [TransCode] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [OverCode5] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [OverCode2] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [OverCode3] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [OverCode4] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [DfltTax] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [TaxPostAcc] [char](1) NULL,
    [AcctStrLe] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [MeaUnit] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [BalDirect] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [UserSign2] [smallint] NULL,
    [PlngLevel] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [MultiLink] [char](1) NULL,
    [PrjRelvnt] [char](1) NULL,
    [Dim1Relvnt] [char](1) NULL,
    [Dim2Relvnt] [char](1) NULL,
    [Dim3Relvnt] [char](1) NULL,
    [Dim4Relvnt] [char](1) NULL,
    [Dim5Relvnt] [char](1) NULL,
    [AccrualTyp] [char](1) NULL,
    [DatevAcct] [int] NULL,
    [DatevAutoA] [char](1) NULL,
    [DatevFirst] [char](1) NULL,
    [SnapShotId] [int] NULL,
    [PCN874Rpt] [char](1) NULL,
    [SCAdjust] [char](1) NULL,
    [BPLId] [int] NULL,
    [BPLName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [SubLedgerN] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [VATRegNum] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [ActId] [nvarchar](210) NOT NULL,
    [ClosingAcc] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [PurpCode] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [RefCode] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [U_COR_FIN_Cls] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [OACT_PRIMARY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AcctCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OASC]    Script Date: 06/Nov/2015 4:28:57 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OASC](
    [SegmentId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ShortName] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [UserSign] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [OASC_PRIMARY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SegmentId] ASC,
    [Code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OBGS]    Script Date: 06/Nov/2015 4:28:57 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OBGS](
    [AbsId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [BaseId] [int] NULL,
    [InitRate] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [Locked] [char](1) NULL,
    [FinancYear] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IsMain] [char](1) NULL,
    [DataSource] [char](1) NULL,
    [RoundSys] [smallint] NULL,
    [UserSign] [smallint] NULL,
    [OcrCode] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [OcrCode2] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [OcrCode3] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [OcrCode4] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [OcrCode5] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [PrjCode] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [U_COR_OcrCode] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [U_COR_PrjCode] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [OBGS_PRIMARY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AbsId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OBGT]    Script Date: 06/Nov/2015 4:28:57 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OBGT](
    [AbsId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AcctCode] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [BgdCode] [int] NULL,
    [FatherCode] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [FthrPrcnt] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [DebLTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [CredLTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [DebSTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [CredSTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [DebRLTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [CrdRLTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [DebRSTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [CrdRSTotal] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrIDRLSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrIDRSSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrICRLSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrICRSSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrODRLSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrOCRLSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrODRSSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FtrOCRSSum] [numeric](19, 6) NULL,
    [FinancYear] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Instance] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserSign] [smallint] NULL,
    [SCNCounter] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [OBGT_PRIMARY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AbsId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Finanse]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Finanse]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Budget]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Budget]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Frozen]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Frozen]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Postable]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [Postable]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Levels]  DEFAULT ((2)) FOR [Levels]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_CashBox]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [CashBox]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_GroupMask]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [GroupMask]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_RateTrans]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [RateTrans]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_TaxIncome]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [TaxIncome]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_ExmIncome]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [ExmIncome]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_ActType]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [ActType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Transfered]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Transfered]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_BlncTrnsfr]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [BlncTrnsfr]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_OverType]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [OverType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_SysMatch]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [SysMatch]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_PrevYear]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [PrevYear]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Protected]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Protected]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_RealAcct]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [RealAcct]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Advance]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [Advance]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_RevalMatch]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [RevalMatch]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_DataSource]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [DataSource]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_LocMth]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [LocMth]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_LocManTran]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [LocManTran]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_LogInstanc]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [LogInstanc]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_ObjType]  DEFAULT ('1') FOR [ObjType]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_ValidFor]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [ValidFor]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_FrozenFor]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [FrozenFor]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Counter]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Counter]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_CfwRlvnt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [CfwRlvnt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_ExchRate]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [ExchRate]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_VatChange]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [VatChange]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_TaxPostAcc]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [TaxPostAcc]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_BalDirect]  DEFAULT ('0') FOR [BalDirect]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_MultiLink]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [MultiLink]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_PrjRelvnt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [PrjRelvnt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Dim1Relvnt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Dim1Relvnt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Dim2Relvnt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Dim2Relvnt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Dim3Relvnt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Dim3Relvnt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Dim4Relvnt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Dim4Relvnt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_Dim5Relvnt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Dim5Relvnt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_AccrualTyp]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [AccrualTyp]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_DatevAutoA]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [DatevAutoA]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_DatevFirst]  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [DatevFirst]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_SnapShotId]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [SnapShotId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_PCN874Rpt]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [PCN874Rpt]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OACT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OACT_SCAdjust]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [SCAdjust]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OBGS] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OBGS_Locked]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [Locked]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OBGS] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OBGS_IsMain]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [IsMain]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OBGS] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OBGS_DataSource]  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [DataSource]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OBGS] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OBGS_RoundSys]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RoundSys]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OBGT] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_OBGT_Instance]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Instance]
GO
```

Comment: Please format your SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make it in 2 parts

First, is to create a new view

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View1]
AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
                         T1.AcctName, T2.Name, T0.DebLTotal AS 'ANNUAL BUDGET KSH', T0.DebRLTotal AS 'UTILISED BUDGET', T3.Name AS Expr1, T3.Code, 
                         T0.DebLTotal - T0.DebRLTotal AS 'BALANCE BUDGET',
                             (SELECT        { fn CONCAT(T3.Code, T3.Name) } AS Expr1
                               WHERE        (T3.SegmentId = '1')) AS 'Project',
                             (SELECT        { fn CONCAT(T3.Code, T3.Name) } AS Expr1
                               WHERE        (T3.SegmentId = '2')) AS 'Distt'
FROM            dbo.OBGT AS T0 INNER JOIN
                         dbo.OACT AS T1 ON T0.AcctCode = T1.AcctCode INNER JOIN
                         dbo.OBGS AS T2 ON T0.Instance = T2.AbsId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.OASC AS T3 ON T3.SegmentId = '1' AND T3.Code = T1.Segment_1 OR T3.SegmentId = '2' AND T3.Code = T1.Segment_2

GO
```

and then to select from that view as below

```
SELECT        View1.*
FROM            View1
WHERE        (Project = N'100') AND (Distt = N'001')
```

Comment: your code is giving me error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. i checked, but could not get out from it. Please check

Comment: Its problem with so many sub queries within one select statement . Please check and paste again ..@Niraj Doshi

Comment: you can try assigning name to your inner select query. I have modified it by adding `AS RES` and then selecting Project and Distt. Let me know if you have any problem with that. As I don't have your actual tables I cannot work with them. You can try [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) if you want to post table structure and provide a link here.

Comment: niraj i am still getting Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
No column name was specified for column 4 of 'RES'.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
The column 'Name' was specified multiple times for 'RES'. error.. I am new here . please tell me how i can  provide you link. and data structure.

Comment: can you tell me the solution please?

Comment: @KaurSukh: I cannot work on the query without table structure. You can create the script of your tables and post it here or may be on SqlFiddle as I mentioned in above comment

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=script.sql)  Please download this file and run ..

Comment: This is just link to drop box, why dont you edit your question and paste script there

Comment: please check the updations

Comment: whenevr i tried to select both Project and Distt as you written in query. then no data is coming up.one option is working one a time. if you check..please have a look on this.. i tried alot to sort it out.please help